# mod_rewrite for Codeigniter on Network Solutions

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter 2.1 installation that is working properly on my local testing server (XAMPP), however when I have moved this to a testing subdomain on my Network Solutions hosting I cannot get the .htaccess to remove the index.php. I have tried the rewrite path as "/htdocs/test" and /test but I still get the following error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
#Submitted by Michael Radlmaier (mradlmaier)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My subdomain is housed at /htdocs/test

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: Could you paste the message from your error log?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is most likely with the httpd.conf, there isn't much you can do outside contact your host support if you do not have the ability to edit this yourself. If you are able to edit your Apache configuration on your host you can post that and we can help you out.

The module is loaded but may not allow your directory to rewrite, specifically not letting it Follow Symbolic Links, which is how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure your have the mod_rewrite module installed in apache. Kill the script at the top of the MAIN index.php file:

```
<?php die(var_dump(apache_get_modules())); ?>
```

If you do not see `mod_rewrite` anywhere it is not installed.

To install it, run the following command on your server (If you have access),

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

That then enabled mod_rewrite for me and it worked fine.

If you do not have root access, you may have to contact customer support and see if they can enable it for you.